# Price switch looping through all divs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I've created a vue component so I can toggle through some pricing options, but I'm not sure how best to loop through all options.

I can loop through the first item using this

```
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.isEnabled = !this.isEnabled;
    let priceMonthly = document.querySelectorAll(".price-monthly");
    let priceYearly = document.querySelectorAll(".price-yearly");
    priceMonthly.classList.toggle("hidden");
    priceYearly.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
}
```

I've tried this as a way to loop through all prices in the plans div

```
methods: {
  toggle() {
    this.isEnabled = !this.isEnabled;
    function togglePrice() {
      let plans = document.querySelector("#plans");
      let priceMonthly = document.querySelectorAll(".price-monthly");
      let priceYearly = document.querySelectorAll(".price-yearly");

      for (var i = 0; i < plans.length; i++) {
        priceMonthly.classList.toggle("hidden");
        priceYearly.classList.toggle("hidden");
      }
    }

    togglePrice();
  }
}
```

This is how I set the pricing in the planItem component:

```
<span class="text-4xl font-bold price-monthly">{{ planMonthlyPrice }}</span>
<span class="text-4xl font-bold price-yearly hidden">{{ planYearlyPrice }}</span>
```

and here is the main div in the plan component:

```
<div id="plans" class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 flex-wrap gap-4 mt-24">
   <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you realize `querySelector` returns the first item that matches? So there is nothing to loop over.

Comment: Oh.... @epascarello

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: I'll update the code because it's still not working

Comment: @debugabug You will want to check [class and style bindings](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM yourself in a Vue app. Just use a class binding: `v-bind:class="{ hidden: isEnabled }"` (or `!isEnabled`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelector returns the first result. You can only have one item with an id. You can not update an collection, you have to loop over each one.

```js
document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".price-yearly, .price-monthly")
    .forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.toggle('hidden')
    })
})
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="plans">
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 1</div>
  <div class="price-yearly hidden">Yearly 1</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 2</div>
  <div class="price-yearly hidden">Yearly 2</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 3</div>
  <div class="price-yearly hidden">Yearly 3</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 4</div>
  <div class="price-yearly hidden">Yearly 4</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 5</div>
  <div class="price-yearly hidden">Yearly 5</div>
</div>

<button id="toggle" type="button">toggle</button>
```

But there is a 100% better way of doing it, add a class to a parent element.

```js
document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector(".plans").classList.toggle('yearly')
})
```

```css
.plans .price-yearly {
  display: none;
}

.plans.yearly .price-yearly {
  display: block;
}

.plans.yearly .price-monthly {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="plans">
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 1</div>
  <div class="price-yearly">Yearly 1</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 2</div>
  <div class="price-yearly">Yearly 2</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 3</div>
  <div class="price-yearly">Yearly 3</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 4</div>
  <div class="price-yearly">Yearly 4</div>
  <div class="price-monthly">Monthly 5</div>
  <div class="price-yearly">Yearly 5</div>
</div>

<button id="toggle" type="button">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Only the main div has an id, the rest are based off classes, but I'll give this a go and tweak if needed.

Comment: Works perfectly, tweaked the first option before you switched it out, but thanks for updating it. Cheers.